# Do multiple categories lead to multiple tests, for nunit test fixtures?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nunit

say that i have the following setup:

```
[TestFixture, Category("aCategory"), Category("anotherCategory")]
public class SomeClass{
   [Test]
   public void SomeTest()
   {
      //testing
   }
}
```

how many times will the `SomeTest` be run? once, with the results shown in both categories, or twice, once for each category?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In NUnit, categories act more like filters than a grouping mechanism.

When selecting the tests to run, you can include or exclude multiple categories, which will affect which tests are selected for a given run of the test suite.

You can assign multiple categories to a test class or method, but for a given run of the suite, each method will only be executed once.